# Whether the amount of data matters in data analytics?

Tags: dataset, bigdata, analytics, data-science, data-analysis

So i want to know whether the data analytics can be done by using a little bit amount of data like 100 to 1000 records stored in a database.If i do so then is it called data analytics?

Somebody saying that it is not at all called data analytics if you are analysing a small amount of data.

So i am confusion the data analytics with big data. So can anyone answer me for this?

My big thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  are analyzing data to discover information to aid decision making, It will be called data analytics irrespective of your size of the data. However, yours might not be called as big data analytics. That would have been what your friend/colleague meant.